# Regex optional group doesn't match

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like this: `/A/B` where `A` and `B` can contain arbitrary characters, except `/`. Sometimes there is a String `_X` in `B` followed by a digit. I want to capture `A`, `B` and `X` with the digit.

I have this regex: `^/(.+)/(.+?(?:_(X\d))?.+?)$`

But It only captures `A` and `B`, never `X` when using `re.match(regex, string)`.

**Update:**
Example Strings could be:

- `/l/_ _X3test` -> should yield groups `l`, `_ _X3test`, `X3`
- `/l/_ X3test` -> should yield groups `l`, `_ X3test`, `None`
- `/l/_ _Xtest` -> should yield groups `l`, `_ _Xtest`, `None`

Comment: If they can contain any character except `/`, you should use `[^/]+` instead of `.+`

Comment: Like this perhaps `^/([^/]+)/([^/_]+)(?:_(X\d))?` https://regex101.com/r/e7fyZq/1 Or `^/([^/]+)/([^/]+?)(?:_(X\d)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/kO63b4/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird your second solution comes close but it cuts off the second group at `_X3` ignoring the `test` (see update)

Comment: @user106745 If will give you 2 groups for the second and third example, do you must have 3 groups? https://regex101.com/r/zN9icH/1

Comment: yes I need all 3

Comment: Thus will give you 3 groups `^/([^/]+)/([^/]+?((?<=_)X\d|$).*)` https://regex101.com/r/APjOG6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
^/([^/]+)/([^/]+?((?<=_)X\d|$).*)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `/([^/]+)` Match `/`, start capture **group 1** and match any char except `/`
- `/([^/]+?` Match `/` and start capture **group 2** matching any char except `/` as least as possible

  - `(` Capture **group 3** *(Nested in group 2)*

    - `(?<=_)X\d` Positive lookbehind to assert _ directly to the left, then match `X` and a single digit
    - `|` Or
    - `$` Assert the end of the string
  - `)` Close group 3
  - `.*` Match 0+ times any char (The rest of the line)
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vqbPJI/1)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"^/([^/]+)/([^/]+?((?<=_)X\d|$).*)"
strings = [
    "/l/_ _X3test",
    "/l/_ X3test",
    "/l/_ _Xtest"
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('l', '_ _X3test', 'X3')]
[('l', '_ X3test', '')]
[('l', '_ _Xtest', '')]
```